# How to have a custom left title for a transfer component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Is there a way I could change the the text from `14 items` as displayed in the following transfer component to

[image]

something like `14 articles`? Is there a way to customize this?

Here is how I generated the above Transfer [Have also placed the same code to replicate the above transfer component in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-meadow-b4nud):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Transfer } from 'antd';

const mockData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  mockData.push({
    key: i.toString(),
    title: `content${i + 1}`,
    description: `description of content${i + 1}`,
    disabled: i % 3 < 1,
  });
}

const oriTargetKeys = mockData.filter(item => +item.key % 3 > 1).map(item => item.key);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    targetKeys: oriTargetKeys,
    selectedKeys: [],
    disabled: false,
  };

  handleChange = (nextTargetKeys, direction, moveKeys) => {
    this.setState({ targetKeys: nextTargetKeys });
  };

  handleSelectChange = (sourceSelectedKeys, targetSelectedKeys) => {
    this.setState({ selectedKeys: [...sourceSelectedKeys, ...targetSelectedKeys] });
  };


  handleDisable = disabled => {
    this.setState({ disabled });
  };

  render() {
    const { targetKeys, selectedKeys, disabled } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Transfer
          dataSource={mockData}
          titles={['Source', 'Target']}
          targetKeys={targetKeys}
          selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onSelectChange={this.handleSelectChange}
          onScroll={this.handleScroll}
          render={item => item.title}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code from ant design so that's the place you should head to first to check the docs [here](https://ant.design/components/transfer/#header). If you scroll down a bit, you will see it has something called `locale` which allows you to do exactly what you are asking for.

This is the code I forked from yours and added `locale`, have a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hoover-tdd3u)

Comment: Is there to have separate text when no content is selected and when atleast one content is selected? For example, default remains `articles` and when one of the content is selected `articles` becomes `selected`. Is it possible?

Comment: @amanda yup thats possible, you have to render it based on condition...
i made a sample code please have a look https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-currying-su89u  ..  articles txt  gonna turn into selected txt when any of the checkbox was selected.

Comment: Is there a way to have separate titles for left and right transfer component? In your example you shared at https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-currying-su89u , if you check the checkbox in the right transfer field, the text in the left component too changes. (For a user this will appear as a bug) Is there a way to handle this?